# Text with emojis to transparent png

Tags: python, png, emoji

I am trying to render a text with emojis to a png with transparent background in python.
I've used [this article](https://kaviraj.me/generating-pdf-containing-emoji-python/) as a starting point and combined it with `imgkit` to convert the html to a png instead of a pdf file.

It works fine but the resulted image has a white background. How can I make the background transparent?

This is what I've done so far:

```
from emojipy import Emoji
import imgkit
import re

config = imgkit.config(wkhtmltoimage="C:\\Program Files\\wkhtmltopdf\\bin\\wkhtmltoimage.exe")
Emoji.unicode_alt = False

def replace_with_emoji_pdf(text, size):
    text = Emoji.to_image(text)
    text = text.replace('class="emojione "', 'height={} width={} background-color: transparent;'.format(size, size))
    text = text.replace('style=""', '')
    return re.sub('alt="'+Emoji.shortcode_regexp+'"', '', text)

my_text = "Here are some emojis "

content = replace_with_emoji_pdf(Emoji.to_image(my_text), 14)

imgkit.from_string(content, 'out.png', config=config, options={'format': 'png'})
```

Comment: Are you sure the emoji are [part of the problem](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Comment: @usr2564301 colored emojis are the reason why I had to go to these extreme measure to render them to an image. Otherwise I'll be using Pillow

Comment: What I meant is: does your work without emoji? If so, they cause the problem. If not, your question is still valid but you can leave out the emoji angle.

Comment: @usr2564301 I am trying to write text on an existing image. The text is a short message written by a user. It can contain regular characters and emojis. I couldn't find a direct way using Pillow or any other library to write text with color emojis on an image, so I am thinking of creating a transparent png and sticking it over the other image. Hence I am using the code above